# why $R[x , y] \over \langle x^2\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $R[0][y]$? Rather it is isomorphic to $R[i][y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

$R$ is the set  of all real number.

$R[x , y] \over \langle x^2 +1\rangle$ isomorphic to $R[i] [y]$

$R[x , y] \over \langle x\rangle $ isomorphic to $R[0][y]$

then why $R[x , y] \over \langle x^2\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $R[0][y]$? Rather it is isomorphic to $R[i][y]$.  Despite the fact that $0$ is a root of $x^2$.

Can anyone explain me in simple language keeping in mind the fact that I only have the basic knowledge of Ring ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What do **you understand** by $\;R[0]\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio $R[0] = R$

Comment: Great. Yet $\;R[x,y]/\langle x^2\rangle\;$ has a non-zero zero divisor, which is the image of $\;x\;$ in the quotient. If $\;R\;$ , whatever that is, has no non-zero zero divisors, you get there a contradiction...

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please elaborate little more?$R$ is the set of all real numbers@DonAntonio

Comment: Fine. Then the ring $\;\Bbb R[x,y]/\langle x^2\rangle\;$ cannot be isomorphic with $\;\Bbb R[0]=\Bbb R\;$ since the last one has no zero divisors, whereas the first one does. And if you only have a basic knowledge in ring theory, why are you trying to cope a question that requires a little more than basic?

Comment: ohh I understood.  so $R[x]  \over ⟨f(x)⟩$
is not always isomorphic to $R[α]$?  Where $R$ is a ring and α is a root of $f(x)$. If yes then can you please tell me under which conditions the above said statement is valid?@DonAntonio

Comment: Your last comment is about a polynomial ring **in one variable**, whereas your question is about a polynomial ring **in two variables** . There are several differences between both things, some of them pretty important...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, everywhere where you wrote $R[x,y]$, you should instead have $R[x]$.

You seem to be working under the misunderstanding that $R[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is equal to $R[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$. This is only true when $p(x)$ is an *irreducible* polynomial over $R$, meaning it cannot be factored into smaller real polynomials. The polynomial $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $R$, so you can say $R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle=R[i],$ where $i^2+1=0$. Note that $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb C$, but that does not matter.

In your case, $x^2=x\cdot  x$ is reducible, so you cannot say that $R[x]/\langle x^2\rangle=R[0]$. The best you can say is that every element of $R[x]/\langle x^2\rangle$ is of the form $ax+b$, where $x$ is a symbol which satisfies $x\neq 0$ and $x^2=0$.

Comment: Why? Is $R[x,y] \over <x^2+1>$ not a valid ring?@Mike Earnest

Comment: @INDIAN It is a valid ring, but $R[x,y]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is not the same as $R[i]$, as you wrote. Rather, $R[x,y]/\langle x^2+1\rangle=R[i][y]$, which is the ring of polynomials whose coefficients are in $R[i]$.

Comment: $R[x,y] \over <x^2+1 ,y>$ is isomorphic to $R[ i , 0]$. Am I right?@Mike Earnest

Comment: Yes, to your last comment.